# Postgres match operator @@

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

I'm trying to figure out how exactly does @@ operator work in postgres.

I have the two queries:

```
SELECT description FROM product WHERE description @@ '%apple%'
SELECT description FROM product WHERE description @@ 'apple'
```

The two queries return the same number of rows. Apparently postgres removes all non 
alfanumeric characters from the query. Is this actually the case?

I can also do `@@ '@apple..,,.'` and I still get the same number of results.

Answer (score 1):

@@ operator is part of TSearch2 Full Text Search Engine. It does remove such characters, by default. The topic of TSearch2 is **way** too big to include it all here, so I'll just point you to [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already red the link before posting the question, but it doesn't say anything about how the query is preprocessed.

Comment: Of course it does. Right side of @@ is tsquery. And tsquery is passed through the same parsers and dictionaries as tsvector.