# What does '@@DEBUG' mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

As the title puts, I really don't know what `@@DEBUG` or some other `@@stringName` mean in JavaScript I mean.

Anybody got an idea there?

Many thanks

---

I've saw it used via string literal, or a variable, as follows:

```
// the 1st scene
angular.module('myApp', []).value('appConst', {'dbServer' : '@@DBSERVER'});

// the 2nd scene
if (@@DEBUG) {
  window.root = $rootScope;
}
// some other logic
```

Thx, all!

---

Now that, I've found out where does this double '@' come from, it's from my grunt, build system, as follows:

```
// In my grunt's replace task
replace : {
  server: {
    replacements: [{
      from: /@@DBSERVER/g,
      to: yeomanConfig.devSettings.DEV_DBSERVER
    }, {
      from: /@@DEBUG/g,
      to: 'true'
    }]
  }
}
```

Thx alot, all of the participants.

Comment: I have never seen that before. Are you sure it's in a JavaScript script? please provide more context.

Comment: do you mean the jsdoc specifiers, you can check wiki here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc

Comment: @MohamedAliJamaoui: JSDoc tags start only start with one `@`.

Comment: yes that's why i was asking because i have never seen @@debug

Comment: No offense, but why does this question have two up votes? Do people really think that *"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"*? If yes, we have a very different ideas about "research effort" and "clear".

Comment: @FelixKling Have you ever *tried* googling for a phrase that contains special characters?

Comment: @Gustav: Maybe googling for e.g. `@@DEBUG` is not necessary. Maybe the context gives enough other clues for what to look for. I'm not saying that the question is not valid. I'm only saying that it is not upvote-worthy.

Comment: for @MohamedAliJamaoui , I just bumped into this issue in my project recently.. now I guess definitely there is a double @.., it's a string literal sometimes, but in project I do see it is uesd like : if (@@DEBUG) { ... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`@@FOO` is *invalid* as JavaScript grammar** - unless it happens to be inside a comment, string literal or regular expression literal.

Thus, it's either *not* JavaScript or has special meaning (to someone, but *not* JavaScript) in one of the following forms:

```javascript
// @@FOO
"@@FOO";
/@@FOO/;
```

It could also be a processing directive in a build system or template engine or valid grammar in a *different* language; but it is  *not* JavaScript.

Comment: yes, u r right, it's from Grunt, my build system... thx alot :)

Comment: Yep, I just checked my /dist folder, the @@varName is replaced by an array of strings. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

> This is  ASP.NET MVC razor view engine syntax.If you used MVC, you can use this syntax in JavaScript by using razor view. So I think you have little bit confusing for razor syntax with JavaScript.
>
> - Please take a look for [Using Razor within JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript)

and also this type of syntax only can write sql-transaction

please see this image

[image]

Sad News, Google not searching with that symbol on javascript

Comment: Razor syntax starts only with one `@` .

Comment: Yup, @Givi . Correct. But Some time The OP have some confusing keyword or wrote wrong syntax format  .

Comment: Yes, maybe you're right.

Comment: I would like to go with RR, thx, @RameshRajendran

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Whatever the code you're looking at (and you should edit your post to include an example) it is not pure Javascript, because Javascript syntax does not use any @ signs.

If you want to confirm that for yourself, you can go through the [Javascript syntax reference page on the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference).

I've added examples of code that does use @@ here to help you identify your code.

This is most likely **C# Razor** syntax:

```
<span>In Razor, you use the 
@@foo to display the value 
of foo</span>
```

It is used to escape the @ when you want to print the @ and not a variable.

Source: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

It could be **Ruby** syntax:

```
def self.debug
  return @@debug
end
```

In Ruby @@ indicates a class variable.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5890199/1005039

It could also be **MySQL** syntax:

```
set debug= 'T';
select @@debug;
@@debug
T
set debug= '+P';
select @@debug;
@@debug
P:T
set debug= '-P';
select @@debug;
@@debug
T
```

In MySQL, @@ indicates variables

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-statement.html

It could also be **PostgreSQL** syntax:

```
SELECT description 
FROM product 
WHERE description @@ '%apple%'
```

Source: [Postgres match operator @@](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835866/postgres-match-operator)

Comment: So, you are saying that it is not related to JavaScript at all? Your answer is proof of why this is a bad question. There just is not enough information to give a definite answer.

Comment: A lot of the questions here are for future searchers. I think that maybe someone else searching for `javascript` and `@@` may find the list of languages that *do* use it as syntax useful.

Comment: thx, I've got that~~It ain't a Js syntax..